# html page refused to apply style bootstrap.min.css

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I am doing a project in **Java** using **Spring Boot** in the **intellij idea** under the management of **Maven**, and *I occasionally have a problem with connecting* **bootstrap.min.css** *on the* **HTML** *page*.

In my case, this problem ***arises spontaneously***, and I could not determine its cause. Even now *I have several absolutely identical projects, and in some of them this problem exists, and in others it has disappeared*.

I connect **bootstrap.min.css** in the same way as on this page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>LoginPage2</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**when I go to the page in the browser, an error message is displayed in the console**:

`Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8081/static/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled`

Comment: Did you download `bootstrap.min.css` ?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded and the problem is not this, **then I gave the answer with a solution to this problem, because I spent a lot of time to fix it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my case it helped me:

- ***replacing this code***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

***with this one***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
```

- ***remove all comments from files*** `bootstrap.min.css` ***and*** `bootstrap.css`
- ***just in case, explicitly register the path to resources in the project with spring boot, for example:***

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private static final String[] CLASS_PATH = {"classpath:/"};

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASS_PATH);
    }
}
```

- ***If there is a spring security, then make sure that there is permission to the resources.***

Answer (score 0):

If you are using local downloaded bootstrap in your PC then, remove integrity and crossorigin from your link. I think this is work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Add in your link tag two more attribute

**type="text/css" media="all"**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: This is a MIME type support exception